# some electric shocks from my own new laptop

Tags: laptop

I have a new laptop from HP and it seems that there is some electric shocks on it when it is plugged in which don't hurt but it does feel comfort for me. After 2 days of using it, it happens to be less now but I'm not sure if it will come back or not!

Do you know any reason for that and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

HP offers the following advice in their [Electrical Shock Safety](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02807128&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) article (specifically, the section on [Preventing tingle current](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c02807128&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en#N119)):

> If you are experiencing a tingle current while using your HP notebook computer, use a 3-wire power cord with your AC adapter and make sure that it is plugged into a grounded (3-hole) power socket. Occasionally, the ground wiring is not well-connected to the earth ground, so the tingle current sensation may still occur even though a 3-wire cord is used. Also consider the following:
>
> If you believe tingle current has caused a problem on your computer, here are a few tips:
>
> - Contact a qualified electrician for help with connecting the power cord's third wire to a metallic grounded structure, such as a plumbing pipe (if allowed by the local electrical code), if you often use the notebook from the same location.
> - Change the AC adapter.
> - Increase ground isolation by placing an anti-static chair mat on the floor below the chair that you typically sit in while using the notebook.
> - Use a different 2-wire power outlet (not a different outlet on the same circuit). Discontinue using a power strip or relocating to a different room may help.

Answer (score 0):

The grounding of the room is not properly done. Just get an electrician to do another grounding for you. But I would recommend you get an extension socket with 3pins (which is grounded) or better still get an extension socket with a surge protector. This worked fine for me.

Comment: I believe the term you mean is ground not earth.

Comment: @Sion The terms "earth" and "earthing" are the British English equivalents of "ground" and "grounding" in US English.

Comment: @Indrek That is indeed good to know. Apologies if there was any insult.