# How can I reduce static electricity while using laptop?

Tags: laptop, static-discharge

Often at winter time I receive an static electric shock from laptop. Also it happens when I sit on the chair with a lot of synthetic fiber.

I have this problem with my laptop which has metallic inserts in plastic chassis. According to comments laptops with aluminium chassis even more susceptible to this.

Also sometimes I get static electric shock from the USB port.
It's frustrating me and it's dangerous for the laptop.

So how this problem could be solved or reduced?

I found [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/407600/145141) and some others, but such things like anti-static chair mat or humidify the air isn't help if you really mobile. You just can't carry it everywhere. Maybe there are some hacks and tricks for this problem?

Comment: Try cotton clothes and leather or non-rubber/plastic shoes to cut down on static build up.